# How to prove that the limit of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{2(x+y)}$ at $(0,0)$ is 0 using the definition of limits?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I got to the point

$|f(x,y)|=\frac{|x||y|}{2\,|x+y|} \leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2|x|+2|y|}$

but then I'm stuck as I can't see how I could make the denominator smaller such that I create a $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ type expression. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $x,y>0$, then is true as $$ \vert f(x,y)\vert \leq \frac{xy}{2x} \leq y.$$ However, as pointed out in the answer below, if you allow for different sign, then limit will not exist.

Comment: It's really interesting to see @Severin, that I don't even need $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to show this. Thank you!

Comment: Your estimate is incorrect. In order to make a quotient (of positive numbers) larger, you smould make the denominator *smaller*, not larger.

Comment: Isn't that what @SeverinSchraven did though? $2|x|< 2|x+y|$  if $x$ and $y$ are both positive

Comment: Your estimate goes in the wrong direction as you use $2\vert x+y\vert \leq 2(\vert x\vert + \vert y\vert)$. I used that $2(x+y)\geq 2x$ (for $x,y>0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the limit is *not* $0$. Note that$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x,-x+x^2)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-1}2=-\frac12.$$

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! Apparently I was just unlucky with my choices.  I tried a few paths, straight lines and even a parabola and they all came to 0, so I just assumed the limit exist (obviously I was wrong), that's why I tried proving my assumption using the definition.